# Calculating a bivariate integral across a circle with its origin @ (1,1)

Tags: calculus

I am using Adams - Calculus, A complete course and a lot of times the book simply states that
\begin{equation}
\iint_D 2x\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y=2\overline x A=2\pi
\end{equation}
for a circle $D$, centered at (1,1) and with radius $1$, $\overline x$ the centroid of my $x$ interval and $A=1^2\pi=\pi$ the area of circle $D$.

I want to derive/calculate this result myself completely algebraically. It's not homework but pure interest and I reckon it should be doable for an easy case like this. My first step was to use polar coordinates, $x_0=1$, $y_0=1$ and $r=1$ in the original relation,
\begin{align}
(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2&=1\\
(r\cos t-1)^2+(r\sin t-1)^2 &=1\\
r^2\cos t+ r^2\sin t -2r\cos t -2r\sin t  &= -1\\
r^2-2r\left(\cos t+\sin t\right)  &= -1\\
\left(r-\cos t -\sin t\right)^2 &= (\cos t + \sin t)^2-1\\
\left(r-\cos t -\sin t\right)^2 &= \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t+2\cos t\sin t-1\\
\left(r-\cos t -\sin t\right)^2 &= 2\cos t\sin t\\
r&= \pm\sqrt{2\cos t\sin t}+\cos t+\sin t.
\end{align}
Now I know that for $0\leq t\leq2\pi$ I have radius $r=\pm\sqrt{2\cos t\sin t}+\cos t+\sin t$. So if I fill in the equation I get
\begin{equation}
\iint_D 2x\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y=\iint_D (2+2r\cos t)r\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
Now imagine I just take
\begin{equation}
r^+=\sqrt{2\cos t\sin t}+\cos t+\sin t
\end{equation}
and use it as my integration boundary, I get
\begin{equation}
\iint_D 2x\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y=\int^{2\pi}_0 \:\mathrm{d}t \int^{\sqrt{2\cos t\sin t}+\cos t+\sin t}_0 (2r+2r^2\cos t)\:\mathrm{d}r
\end{equation}
Which is a horrible expression. What can I do to make it easier/what can I do to calculate the desired solution of (in this case) $2\pi$? I'm probably just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horrible indeed! You're using polar coordinates centered at $(0,0)$ (usual polar coordinates), but your domain is a circle centered elsewhere; this is a good example why polar coordinates aren't great in such a situation.

If you really want to use polar coordinates, then you should center them at the center of the circle. Equivalently, do a change of variables in the integral to move the domain of integration to a circle centered at $(0,0)$ (and in doing so, you'll see where the $\bar x$ term comes from).

Alternatively, you can write $x=1+(x-1)$ (more generally, $x=\bar x +(x-\bar x)$) and split into two integrals. The first integral is the integral of a constant - easy - and gives $2\bar x A$. The second integral is $0$ by horizontal symmetry!

Comment: Your "alternative" idea of writing $x$ as $x\rightarrow x=1+(x-1)$ was actually the best idea! That instantly gives the desired result!